# Implementation of a lock using test and set

Tags: c, operating-system, locks, test-and-set

Below is the code is given in [OSTEP book](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) regarding the implementation of a lock using test and set instruction. My question is that in such implementation, couldn't a thread that is not holding the lock call the unlock function and take away the lock?

```
typedef struct __lock_t {
 int flag;
 } lock_t;

 void init(lock_t *lock) {
 // 0 indicates that lock is available, 1 that it is held
 lock->flag = 0;
 }

 void lock(lock_t *lock) {
 while (TestAndSet(&lock->flag, 1) == 1)
 ; // spin-wait (do nothing)
 }

 void unlock(lock_t *lock) {
 lock->flag = 0;
 }
```

Comment: The book is likely assuming that such a case is a coding mistake that should never happen.

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure if they assume it to be a coding mistake or if it was something that I missed. I'm sure the actual code for such lock would be much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It's assumed that it's a coding error so that case should not be happening.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that in such implementation, couldn't a thread that is not holding the lock call the unlock function and take away the lock?

There's nothing wrong with (e.g.) one thread acquiring a lock, notifying another thread that it can proceed (or maybe spawning a new thread), then the other thread releasing the lock.

Something is very wrong if a single thread acquires a lock and then releases it twice.

To detect bugs (while still supporting all legitimate scenarios), you'd want to detect "`unlock()` called when lock not held". You could do that by using an atomic `TestAndClear()` in the `unlock()`.

If you want to enforce "only the thread that acquired the lock may release the lock" then you have to know which thread acquired the lock, so you have to store a thread ID in the lock when its acquired (e.g. maybe by using an atomic "compare, and exchange if it was equal").